# How to add images to a post without inserting them into the content area of the post editor?

Tags: images, media-library

I'm building a site where I need to be able to add multiple images to a post, but not have them in the regular content of the post.

These images will be used in a gallery above the post.

My client might want to add images to the post itself too, so I can't just set img to display:none in the content div and use a loop to get the image attachments for the post to use.

The wp-e-commerce plugin has an area below it's custom product post type where you can only add images, which is exactly what I'm looking for, but I can't seem to find something similar.

Does anyone know of a plugin, or code snipet to add this type of functionality to a template?

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off-topic here, but [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com) with the [Gallery add-on](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/gallery-field/) is a high-quality, well-supported plugin, and one of the easiest ways to pull this off. I use this on just about every bespoke theme I build for clients.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

its tough to find a good solution to this but you need a custom meta box for file uploads: here is a post that walks you through this and he gives you a meta box class that can handle multiple image uploads. Make sure you also read part two, and dig around in the code so you can learn it for yourself =] http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/04/how-to-create-meta-box-wordpress-post.html, best of luck!!

Comment: Please do not post answer of the form "look here for a the answer". The answer here should stand on its own and be valuable even if that link dies.